# Oracle SQL Developer - TO_CHAR Bugs

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

Bom dia. Estou com um problema/dúvida: Por que não é possível utilizar mais de uma vez TO_CHAR para o mesmo campo? E por que isso influencia no resultado de outros campos? Se alguém souber me explicar, agradeço. :)

Exemplo 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que o "to_char" para um campo que já é "string" , você que converter a "tolerancia" ? to_char é para formatar números e datas , vide https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570

Comment: A coluna não é string, é um CLOB, e eu quero fazer concatenações diferentes com ela.

Comment: clob !! putz !  tentou a DBMS_LOB ? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66748veja tb este exemplo mandando email https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql

Comment: Então tentei, o que acontece, um TO_CHAR funciona, um DBMS_LOB funciona, um de cada também funciona, porém, qualquer um dois dois que eu use pela segunda vez na mesma coluna, buga outra coluna que não tem nada haver com a que to convertendo com o TO_CHAR/DBMS_LOB, os valores ficam zerados como pode ver no print. (a outra coluna é uma BINARY_DOUBLE) .

Comment: Publica no tópico o erro Oracle. O erro Oracle sinaliza isto ? Colunas Blobs tem muitas restrições (quase a ponto de não usá-las <risos>) , aqui onde trabalho o ERP usava um LONG RAW (descontinuado) e algumas colunas ,o que eu fiz foi uma FUNCTION que recebe a chave da linha e lá trata o "blob" retornando a string.

Comment: Eu criei: https://community.oracle.com/message/15634849#15634849

Comment: Não quer me passar a função pra eu dar uma olhada se o problema continuaria acontecendo? Se não quiser de boa, sei que é trabalho pessoal seu. Meu e-mail: gustavosouzadarosa@gmail.com.br . Muito obrigado.

Comment: Te passei ela sem detalhes pois é material da empresa.